# laravel 5.8 doesnt display react view freshly installed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel

i am very new in laravel + react js. I followed the tutorial and i don't know  what is happening why output doesn't out.

Here is my problem. I already installed laravel 5.8 and react js, but when i call the id named example, it doesn't return any view.

Now here is the laravel code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <title>Laravel</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Styles -->

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="example"></div>

        <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

after that here is the react javascript:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default class Example extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row justify-content-center">
                    <div className="col-md-8">
                        <div className="card">
                            <div className="card-header">Example Component</div>

                            <div className="card-body">
                                I'm an example component!
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

if (document.getElementById('example')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('example'));
}
```

the location of the javascript file is in: resources/js for the app.js

Comment: what are you using to compile the js? Laravel Mix?

Comment: @CodeBoyCode please help me, i was just using php artisan preset react from the documentation after i installed laravel

Comment: did you run `npm install && npm run dev` ?

Comment: @CodeBoyCode i used everything nothing helping